# Items repeating in dynamically created TextView in custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have created the custom ListView and items being repeated in the dynamically created textview inside `getView()`.  There is a LinearLayout `ll` inside the xml file, to where I'm adding the dynamically created TextView. Please check the images for clear idea. I think the problem is with `List<ModelClinicList> opList = list.get(position).operatingHoursList;` and `for loop` inside the `getView()`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_list_clinics, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);


        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        final String telePhoneNumber = "tel:"+list.get(position).getTelephoneNumber();
        final String latitude = list.get(position).getLatitude();
        final String longitude = list.get(position).getLongitude();
        final String clinicName = list.get(position).getClinicName();
        holder.tvAddress.setText(list.get(position).getAddress());
        holder.tvClinicName.setText(clinicName);

        List<ModelClinicList> opList = list.get(position).operatingHoursList;

        for (int i = 0; i < opList.size(); i++){
            TableRow tableRows = new TableRow(context);
            tableRows.setLayoutParams(params);
            TextView tvLabel = new TextView(context);

            tvLabel.setLayoutParams(tvParams);

            tvLabel.setText(opList.get(i).dayName);

            holder.ll.addView(tvLabel);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

[image: Before scroll]

[image: After scrolling]

Comment: I think issue is with the opList list. Can you check the size of the list and data in it?

Comment: When the position is 0(zero), List Size -- 8
Inside loop : i 0and dayName Mon
Inside loop : i 1and dayName Tue
Inside loop : i 2and dayName Wed
 Inside loop : i 3and dayName Thu
 Inside loop : i 4and dayName Fri
 Inside loop : i 5and dayName Sat
 Inside loop : i 6and dayName Sun
Inside loop : i 7and dayName PH

Comment: i think the problem is with the holder. create new holder in else part also.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one dynamic or static ListView and then write one CustomAdapter.

Inside the adapter write one TextView and pass the list to the adapter. ( I don't know the size of list)